# how can I use a function to exit for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I want to write a function to exit a for loop.
Typically, we can

```py
for i in range(10):
    if i==8:
       break
```

I hope to write a function like,

```py
def interrupt(i):
   if i == val:
      ...


for i in range(10):
   interrupt(i)
```

**Edit**

I understand the mechanism and why I can't do this now. Just out of curiosity, does python offer something like 'macro expansion', so that I don't actually create a function, but a name to repalce the code block?

Comment: You can have `interrupt` throw an exception of some kind and catch it in your for loop, breaking, or doing whatever you please after excepting it.

Comment: How about `continue` ?

Comment: @CeliusStingher, `break` and `continue` do different things.

Comment: Both exit the loop?

Comment: @CeliusStingher And neither one can cross function-call boundaries; they only apply to the innermost loop they appear in lexically.

Comment: `break` exits the loop; `continue` skips the rest of the body and gets the next value from the iterator.

Comment: well, thank you guys. I understand now. Just out of curiosity, does python offer something like 'macro  expansion', so that I don't actually create a function, but a name to repalce the code block?

Comment: No, Python does not offer any kind of macro expansion. Such constructs usually cause more problems than they solve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. The `for` loop continues until an explicit `break` statement is encountered *directly* in the loop, or until the iterator raises `StopIteration`.

The best you can do is examine the return value of `interrupt` or catch an exception raised by `interrupt`, and use that information to use `break` or not.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to throw a break, you can fake it a bit like this for example:

```
def interrupt(i):
    if i > 2:
        return True
    return False

for i in range(10):
    if interrupt(i):
        break

    #.. do loop stuff
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code will solve your problem:

```
def interrupt(i, pred=lambda x:x==8):
    if pred(i):
        raise StopIteration(i)

try:
    for i in range(10):
        interrupt(i)
except StopIteration as e:
    print('Exit for loop with i=%s' % e)

# output: Exit for loop with i=8
```

The scheme is simple, and works in general with any kind of exception:

1. Write a function `foo()` that raises one or more exceptions when one or more events occur
2. Insert the call to the function `foo()` in the **try-except** construct
3. Manage exceptions in **except** blocks